# Docker share the common bins and libs?

Tags: docker

Couple of tutorial including this one https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1xo-0gCVhTU.. see at 9th minute, says docker shares the common bins/libs

Consider I have below Dockerfile from ubuntu old version say 14.0.4

```
FROM php:7.2-apache
COPY ./ /var/www/html/
EXPOSE 80
```

Now if I run three containers of above image file, does it mean all three containers will share apache and php bins/libs except the main
app code at `/var/www/html/` ?

Answer (score 3):

Yes and not. Each container runs in its own isolated environment so if you run three containers from the same image in the same host, they will not share the filesystems.

The libs/bins will be equivalent since the three containers come from the same image, but not the same since each container has 'copied' the image and it's being run in an isolated environment.

I think the point of the tutorial is that you can use the same image to run all your php apps, saving resources like disk space.

Here are two short posts about the insights of docker images and containers:

[How Docker Images Work: Union File Systems For Dummies](https://terriblecode.com/blog/how-docker-images-work-union-file-systems-for-dummies/)

[Whats Even A Container](http://%20https://jvns.ca/blog/2016/10/10/what-even-is-a-container/)

Comment: From https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24145925/docker-sharing-dependencies looks like they will share the common libs/bin like dependencies from base image. I did not get your two points 1. `they will not share the filesystems. ` what do you mean by not sharing the file system here ? 2. Also you said `The libs/bins will be equivalent ` are you saying libs/bins will be shared or not ?

Comment: It's hard to explain in few words. They will not share the filesystems: each container runs in a different linux namespace, so if you remove, for example, the php binary in one container, that will not affect to other containers in the same host.

Comment: Ok get your point. But what if if i delete the some file from image file itself, will it impact already running containers ? Or container also create the copy of files from image ?